# Best way to handle async data loading in firebase and vue

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

Hi I am wondering what the best way to handle async code inside of a vue app. I basically want to pull data from firebase and then run my setup function. My page is fully contingent on the data pulled from firebase and so i don't mind if it doesnt load while firebase pulls data.

I keep getting undefined errors etc. even as i try different async await methods. I want to access this data inside of the setup function before page renders.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Say the data from firebase is called `myData`. Give the markup two branches: one for when data is ready, and one for when data isn't ready.

```
<div v-if="myData">
  markup assumes myData is ready
</div>
<div v-else>
  markup doesn't use myData, perhaps indicates "loading..."
</div>
```

In the code, probably early in the lifecycle, initialize `myData` with the result of the async work.

Comment: Ok awesome thanks a lot! Is this the standard best practice or more of a work around

Comment: I think that's a good starting point from @danh. For one thing, error management is still missing. Which is basically another layer with v-if/v-else.

Comment: @atx123n, yes, I think it’s right to say that this is the best way.  The job of the UI is to present system state to the user. What this UI is saying is that “uninitialized, but working on it” is a valid, albeit temporary, state.